# Function does not get called

Tags: javascript

I am working on a following javascipt file

```
var utility = (function () {

    var i = 1;
    return {

        nameGen: function () {
            var name = "Number Of Candidate:" + i;
            i = i + 1;
            return name;
        }
    }


} ());

var name1 = utility.nameGen();
var name2 = utility.nameGen();
var name3 = utility.nameGen();
```

I am calling above javascript code from my html but it is not working?

Comment: Works fine as-is in Firebug Console...

`Number Of Candidate:1`
`Number Of Candidate:2`
`Number Of Candidate:3`

What result are you expecting?

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j262f/ works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran it here (with Firefox 29 and Chrome 34.0.1847.131 and Internet Explorer 9), and added `console.log()` calls to output the result -

```
var utility = (function () {
    var i = 1;
    return {
        nameGen: function () {
            var name = "Number Of Candidate:" + i;
            i = i + 1;
            return name;
        }
    }
} ());

var name1 = utility.nameGen();
var name2 = utility.nameGen();
var name3 = utility.nameGen();
console.log(name1);
console.log(name2);
console.log(name3);
```

I got the output

```
Number Of Candidate:1
Number Of Candidate:2
Number Of Candidate:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the function like this:

```
}) ();
```

Comment: Either form of self-execute notation is acceptable.

Comment: The vars are being populated with the string in either case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write OOP JS you should do something like:

```
function Utility() {
    this.candidates = 1;
    this.nameGen = function () {
        var name = 'number of candidates' + this.candidates;
        this.candidates++;
        return name;
    }
}

var utility = new Utility();
utility.nameGen(); // outputs "number of candidates1"
utility.nameGen(); // outputs "number of candidates2"
utility.nameGen(); // outputs "number of candidates3"
```

You can read more about OOP JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).